# Docker alternative for Python to Nodejs for Proxy Ins

Tags: python, docker

```
RUN npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

The above line is for the NodeJs format in the Docker File

I am looking for an alternative to the above syntax in Python

```
ENV https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Will this work ?

Answer (score 1):

If you do that in your dockerfile then you should be able to access the environment variable in python using the code:

```
import os

proxy = os.environ["https-proxy"]
```

If that's sufficient, you're done. If you need to do something else with it we'd need more information about your goal.

Comment: Thank You .. I actually have a python flask file which uses the templates containing html files . That is all the app has , I wanted to create a docker file for the same.

Comment: It seems like the `RUN npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080` is configuring npm to use a proxy for subsequent npm download actions inside the dockerfile. Python itself doesn't download anything, but utilities like `pip` do. 

According to the documentation for pip (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-a-proxy-server) it will use an environment named `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` or `no_proxy`.